# Translation of bubble needed

Tags: grammar

I'd like a translation of what is being said in the third window bubble.

[image]

It begins with その他 and is just that bubble.
I translated it as:

> "In addition, he made some other various things which did cost some money, but. . ."

And then it continues in the next bubble.
I am just curious as how this is meant to be translated. I just want a quite literal translation of it. To me it sounds like the speaker is receiving various kinds of money that is being made.

Since I knew from the context that such is not the case, I still feel vexxed by the fact that my translating skills are so horrid. for example 色々と means to me not various things but just "various" since it doesn't have the を particle. the には, 作っていただいた金 (I) got to make for me money?!? just sounds weird. Please help.

It might be because the japanese are so horrendously bad at marking out (assumed) words like say. I also had it make other various things(.) (WHICH) it did cost some money but. Since the japanese don't have any good 'which' words, it is usually portrayed in って. But since 作っていただいた金 could mean 'money that I (had) him make for me, or something.

Answer (score 4):

You should parse it as:

> その他にも彼には色々と作っていただいた。
>   金はかかったけど。

Literally: "Other than this, we had him make various things, too.
It did cost some money, though."

Comment: So there is a end dot after itadaita? Which could be kind of phrased as (which did). Alright thanks.